# Running Query Result Which Is a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, pgadmin

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4 and PG Admin. I have a table with a field that contains prepared SQL statements. I select a specific record based on 2 variables. I want to run the result as it's own SQL statement. Desirably the record chosen would be dynamic based on altering the two variables. Here is an abbreviated example:

> select search_expression_used from metrics where year_month = '2014_12' and id = 1

This will return a SQL statement which I want to run:

> select * from ....

Is there a way to run the result of a SQL statement as its own SQL statement, with variables? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: @sqluser he is using PostgreSQL

Comment: You need to write a function that uses dynamic SQL

Comment: I have a very basic understanding of dynamic SQL, but how do you pass the result of a SQL statement to a variable? I can set the sql text to be 'select search_expression_used from metrics where year_month = ''2014_12'' and id = 1', but I can't figure out how to take the result an set the variable to it.

Answer (score 0):

This could achieved probably programmatically. 
Get the result query and using cursor to execute it again.

I actually don't quite get the question as you said you are using the admin console, in that case why not just paste the result onto the query box and hit run again?

Comment: Running in the admin console works for me, but theSQL is going to be used in a process by non-SQL users. One developer made a front end tool that provides inputs for user, so they don't see any SQL. We can create new reports with SQL in the back end, but PostgeSQL needs to be able to run it. As long as there is a function I can create that runs the SQL that results from the original SQL statement, we won't be able to implement this. Thanks for your help